# How to get Twitter's Impression and Reach with R twitteR package?

Tags: r, twitter

This question is about measuring twitter impressions and reach using R.

I'm working on a twitter analysis of "[People voice about Lynas Malaysia through Twitter Analysis with R](http://blog.cloudstat.org/post/18451446920/people-voice-about-lynas-malaysia-through-twitter-analys)" . To be more perfect, I wish to find out how to measure impressions, reach, frequency and so from twitter.

Definition:

1. Impressions: The aggregated number of followers that have been exposed to a brand/message.
2. Reach: The total number of unique users exposed to a message/brand.
3. Frequency: The number of times each unique user reached is exposed to a message.

My trial: #1.

From my understanding, the impression is the followers numbers of the total tweeters that tweet specific "keyword".

For #1. I made one:

```
rdmTweets <- searchTwitter(cloudstatorg, n=1500)
tw.df=twListToDF(rdmTweets)
n <- length(tw.df[,2])

S <- 0
X <- 0

for (i in 1:n) {

tuser <- getUser(tw.df$screenName[[i]])
X <- tuser$followersCount
S <- S + X 

}

S
```

But the problem occurred will be

```
Error in .self$twFromJSON(out) : 
  Error: Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.
```

For #2. and #3., still don't have any ideas, hope to get helps here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having for #1 has nothing to do with R nor your code, is about the # of calls you have made to the Twitter Search API and that it exceeded the 150 calls you have by default.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you are able to mix and match several components of the API to get the results you need,

You can read more in their docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting